# How to add exactly one tab before method in googles checkstyle.xml

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

so I want maven checkstyle plugin build to fail when one method is more than one tab in (4 spaces) simple example is

```
class test {
    public void test1 () {} //4 spaces in so thats ok
     public void test2 () {} //5 spaces in i want maven build to fail
}
```

I can't find someone that has a solution to this problem so I need help

Comment: Either post your solution as an answer to your question, or delete your question completely. Posting your answer within your question is inappropriate and unhelpful.

Comment: you are right i just didn't figure out i can post under my post thank you very much and I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved add under TreeWalker this

```
<module name="Indentation">
        <property name="basicOffset" value="4"/>
        <property name="braceAdjustment" value="0"/>
        <property name="caseIndent" value="4"/>
        <property name="throwsIndent" value="8"/>
        <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="8"/>
        <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="4"/>
    </module>
```

that's how I fixed my problem